# Visual Basic wait without stopping program?

Tags: vb.net

I want to make my program wait 1 second or so before my player can move again but Sleep freezes everything in the program... 
How would I make one event wait not the whole program?

Answer (score 0):

use timer to perform the task.

just disable the particular UI component and start the timer once the timer runs for 1 second or more re-enable the specific UI component.

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

is only helpful in background threads.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
```

The values are in milliseconds

Comment: I don't have 15 rep yet, i would tho :P